# Calculation for status in Archer GRC based on date

Tags: rsa, archer, rsa-archer-grc

Trying to create a status field based on a number of Value Lists that users select from, but a request has been made that we check a date field  for a value to ensure an estimated date has been set so that the calculation can determine if the status of the record is "In Progress", "Late" or "Not Started".

Comment: If you don't check the value first, will an error be generated somehow?  if so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `ISEMPTY()` function within your calculated field to verify that the date field contains a value.  Then, use the `DATEDIF` function to determine if record is late or in progress.

Comment: If you don't check the value first, will an error be generated somehow?  if so, how and where?

Comment: Within the settings of the calculated field you can choose to display the error message within the calculated field itself. Beyond that, you should check the logs generated in the back end inside the application folder.